# Definir una interfaz en base a otra pero con tipos de propiedades diferentes

Tags: typescript

teniendo la siguiente interface inicial en typescript:

```
interface IA {
  a1 : string;
  a2 : number;
}
```

en base a la interface `IA` definir otra interface con los mismas propiedades (o atributos) pero con diferente tipado:

```
interface IB {
  a1 : object;
  a2 : string[];
}
```

si bien el ejemplo es muy sencillo (2 propiedades en la interface), tengo el inconveniente cuando es una interface inicial con 10 o más propiedades, pues literalmente me da “flojera” tener que repetir todas las propiedades en la definición de la otra interface.

he intentado lo siguiente de las utilidades de Typescript:

```
type IB = Record<keyof IA, any>;
```

o esta con mas opción de personalización:

```
interface IB extends Record<keyof IA, any>{
   //...aqui mas propiedades personalizadas
}
```

pero no resuelve completamente el problema porque convierte todas las propiedades de la interface `IB` a un solo tipo de valor (en este caso a `any`).

¿Existe alguna utilidad de typescript para lograrlo?

Comment: no le encuentro la utilidad pero aquí hay alguien que preguntó lo mismo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771307/typescript-dynamically-create-interface

Comment: ¿Porque no usas union types en IA? ya que dices que tu debes definir las interfaces

Comment: @LPZadkiel, gracias por el enlace, como dice en la respuesta, es una solución algo problemática... pero funciona, lo detallo mas en la respuesta.

Comment: @g.4 te agradezco un poco mas de información en lo que te refieres a unión...

Comment: [Union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

Comment: @g.4 unión es muy útil, pero si la uso para este caso, algo así: `type TUnion = IA | IB` regreso al inicio del problema, si las propiedades de la interface `IA` y `IB` son las mismas las tengo que repetir en cada definición pero si ¿`IA` tiene muchas propiedades?, o si ¿deseo cambiar el nombre de algunas propiedades de `IA` o agregar mas propiedades? también debo cambiar los nombres de las propiedades en `IB` y/o agregar las nuevas propiedades.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la respuesta de: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771307/typescript-dynamically-create-interface , y haciendo unas modificaciones se puede solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
/**define las `key` comunes 
(la definición en la que se basarán las interfaces)*/
type TBase<Ta1, Ta2> = {
    a1 : Ta1;
    a2 : Ta2;
    //... aquí muchas mas de propiedades
}
/**define tipos a usar en IA */
type TMapSchemaIA = {
  'string' : string;
  'number' : number;
   //... aqui los demás tipos de cada propiedad
}
/**define tipos a usar en IB */
type TMapSchemaIB = {
  'object': object;
  'stringA': string[];
  //... aquí los demás tipos de cada propiedad
}
/**el tipado que hace la magia */
type TSchemaGenerator<TMapSchema, TBase extends Record<string, keyof TMapSchema>> = {
 -readonly [K in keyof TBase]: TMapSchema[TBase[K]]
}
//Definicion de alto nivel con type:
type IA = TSchemaGenerator<TMapSchemaIA, TBase<'string', 'number'>>;
type IB = TSchemaGenerator<TMapSchemaIB, TBase<'object', 'stringA'>>;
//implementacion:
let a:IA = {a1:"Hola", a2:3};
let b:IB = {a1:{}, a2:["Hola Array"]};
```

o si se quiere la definición con interfaces:

```
//Definición de alto nivel con interface:
interface IA extends TSchemaGenerator<TMapSchemaIA, TBase<'string', 'number'>>{
    //... opcional mas personalización
}
interface IB extends TSchemaGenerator<TMapSchemaIB, TBase<'object', 'stringA'>>{
    //... opcional mas personalización
}
```

en un principio parece más engorrosa que la solución directa (la de definir otra interface repitiendo todas las propiedades) pero si la interface base tiene muchas propiedades o se requiere un gran número de interfaces que se basen en ella puede ser útil.

Comment: Le encuentro utilidad si no se saben los valores de `a/b` ahead of time, pero en este caso parece que los define el dev, aunque es un buen ejercicio para estudiar generics. Y me perdí en la parte de `Record` cuando se supone que ya tenemos `TBase` con generics.

Comment: @g.4 tener presente: `type TBase` definido al inicio y el `TBase` contenido en la definición de `type TSchemaGenerator` **están en contextos diferentes**  por afán los nombré igual.

En realidad, en la definición `type TSchemaGenerator` fue tomada casi idéntica a la respuesta del enlace pero a profundidad no comprendo su funcionamiento, solo la adapte a la solución que necesitaba